How to combine the animations of two different cameras into one continuous animation?
I have the scene below and I want to transition from the top camera into the bottom one as soon as the top camera is done with its animation. I want to do this while maintaining the existing interpolation and curves for each individual camera, so that the transition is smooth.
The top camera has 2 constraints, one is a Child of that will follow the cube, and the other one is a Track to constraint that will always face the camera towards the cube. The bottom camera has all it's animation baked into keyframes.
I know I can get them very close to each other and then switch the cameras. I can also attach the bottom cam to the top one and make sure it starts its animation where the top cam comes to a full stop. I can also copy the keyframes... But none of these give me a smooth transition between the two animations.
What's the best way to go about this?
https://imgur.com/a/XHDMHjT

if switching from a camera to the other doesn't work, I guess the only solution is to use only one camera from start to end?

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

I tried to save it as a GIF to upload but the file size was over the limit.
